# How can i assign 2d array to 3d array?

Tags: matrices

how to asign 2 dimesion array to 3 dimension array if it is not possible then how can i assign each 2 dimension array to 3 dimension array in for loop (in matlab)

for examle math

```
A(1)=   1   3   5 

A(2)=   5   8   11

B(1)=    1  3   5

         5  8   11
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Is this a programming question? Might it be better understood at a programming website than at a math website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a = [1 2 3];
> b =[3 4 5];
>
> B = [a;b] will give you the answer.